# Find a Specific Minor in a Graph (Exercise from Diestel)

Tags: graph-theory

> Let $\varepsilon(G)$ be $|E(G)|/|V(G)|$, and let $\delta(G)$ denote the minimun degree of $G$. Given a graph $G$ with $\varepsilon(G)\ge k \in \mathbb{N}$ , find a minor $H\prec G$ such that $\delta(H)\ge k\ge |H|/2$.

This is the Exercise 20 in the fourth edition of Reinhard Diestel's *Graph Theory*.

Comment: I suppose $\delta$ is the smallest degree, but what is $\varepsilon$?

Comment: @Chris in Diestel's book $\varepsilon(G) = |E(G)|/|V(G)|$.  Equivalently, $\varepsilon(G)$ is half of the average degree of $G$.

Comment: The exercise can be found on page 197 in chapter 7 about extremal graph theory.